# How to test useEffect combined with useDispatch hooks using jest/enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

How can i test if `useEffect` called `dispatch` with `requestMovies` on mount?

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

export const requestMovies = page => ({
  type: MoviesTypes.REQUEST_MOVIES,
  page,
});

const MoviesShowcaseList = () => {
  const { page } = useShallowEqualSelector(state => state.movies);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const fetchNextMoviesPage = () => {
    dispatch(requestMovies(page + 1));
  };

  useEffect(fetchNextMoviesPage, []);

  return (...);
};
```

Answer (score 5):

First, we use [`jest.mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules) to get `useDispatch` mocked:

```
import { useDispatch, useShallowEqualSelector } from 'react-redux';

jest.mock('react-redux');
```

Second, we render our element with `mount`(`shallow` [does not run `useEffect`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2011) since React's own shallow renderer does not do that).

```
const wrapper = mount(<MoviesShowcaseList />);
```

If using modern version of enzyme we don't need to do anything additional with `act()` since it's [already in Enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/pull/2034).

And finally we check if `useDispatch` has been called:

```
expect(useDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
  type: MoviesTypes.REQUEST_MOVIES,
  0,
});
```

All together(with mocking `useShallowEqualSelector`):

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

jest.mock('react-redux');

it('loads first page on init', () => {
  useShallowEqualSelector.mockReturnValueOnce(0); // if we have only one selector
  const wrapper = mount(<MoviesShowcaseList />);
  expect(useDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(useDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    type: MoviesTypes.REQUEST_MOVIES,
    0,
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting `Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function Received has type:  function
    Received has value: [Function useDispatch]`, I also need to wrap the component in `Provider` which fails if i mock `react-redux` outside of the test

Comment: I don't think you really need to wrap into `Provider` once you are using hooks. Just provide other hooks with mocked values. As for error it sounds like `react-redux`(`useDispatch` specifically) is not mocked but this looks weird. May you provide full-size code snippet you run?

Comment: `useShallowEqualSelector` use `useSelector` so i guess i need to mock this one too ? I'm pretty new to testing sorry, Do you want a full size code of the tests/component or a small working app?

Comment: missed that part.  yes, you may mock `useShallowEqualSelector` as well(until there are a lot of selectors and it's hard to distinguish). I appended sample.

Comment: I don't see how this test would pass. useDispatch is going to be called on every render, with no argument. I think that Asaf wants to test whether dispatch has been called with the correct action, and this is not what's being tested here.